# Problems to calculate sine or cosine function inside FFT java class- Android studio

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the Fast Fourier Transform Java class in Android Studio. I would like to create a sinusoidal function but there is a simple problem:
my FFT function needs a double [] inside and using for cicle to create a sine function that I can not use inside.
My question is: how to create a sine function to use it in my FFT function?
I'm new to Android Studio, probably the answer is simple and easy but I have no idea of ​​right now.
Please suggest me how I could do it.
Thank you
Here my FFT.java class:

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.Math;

public class Fft {

    public static double FFT(Double[] in, int size, double samplingFrequency) {
        double temp = 0;
        double POMP = 0;
        double frequency;
        double[] output = new double[2*size];

        for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++)
            output[i] = 0;

        for(int x=0;x<size;x++){
            output[x]=in[x];
        }

        DoubleFft1d fft = new DoubleFft1d(size);
        fft.realForward(output);

        for(int x=0;x<2*size;x++){
            output[x]= Math.abs(output[x]);
        }

        for(int p=12; p<size; p++) {// 12 was chosen because it is a minimum frequency that we think people can get to determine heart rate.
            if(temp < output[p]) {
                temp = output[p];
                POMP = p;

            }
        }

//      if (POMP < 12) {
//      POMP = 0;
//      }

        frequency = POMP*samplingFrequency/(2*size);
        return frequency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a discrete (sampled) sine signal using:

```
X[n] = A * sin(2*PI*fo*n*ts)
```

Where `X[n]` is the value of the sine at index n (0, 1, 2, 3...); A the amplitude; `fo` is the sine function frequency and `ts` is the sampling period.
Also, for sine could be useful:

```
(fs = 1/ts)
```

Where `fs` is the sampling frequency.